# Android studio - making new app

Tags: android

I was trying to make an app in android Studio. I click build>generate signed apk and then choose destination and finish. it throws me that code:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexRelease'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\username\AndroidstudioProjects\Myproject\app\build\intermediates\dex\release --input-list=C:\Users\username\AndroidstudioProjects\Myproject\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\release\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

remove `android-support-v4.jar` in **libs** folder

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your top level gradle file

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```